# RecyclerView throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My recycler view is throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException`:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.msit.example.bunty.regform.entities.DataStore.getDataStore()' on a null object reference                                                                    at com.msit.example.bunty.regform.adapters.MyRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount(MyRecyclerAdapter.java:65)

MyRecyclerAdapter.java

```
package com.msit.example.bunty.regform.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.R.*;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.msit.example.bunty.regform.R;
import com.msit.example.bunty.regform.entities.DataStore;
import com.msit.example.bunty.regform.entities.UserData;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**l
 * Created by bunty on 1/5/16.
 */

public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    DataStore userDataStore=new DataStore();
    //ArrayList<UserData> userDataStore=new ArrayList<UserData>();
    public MyRecyclerAdapter(DataStore userDataStore)
    {
        this.userDataStore=userDataStore;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

       holder.fNameView.setText(userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).getFirstName());
        holder.lNameView.setText(userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).getLastName());
        holder.addressView.setText(userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).getAddress());
        holder.cityView.setText(userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).getCity());
        final String city=userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).city;
        holder.cityView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),city,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(!userDataStore.getDataStore().isEmpty()&&userDataStore.getDataStore()!=null) {
            return userDataStore.getDataStore().size();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

         TextView fNameView;
         TextView lNameView;
         TextView addressView;
         Button cityView;
         CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            fNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fn_view);
            lNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ln_view);
            addressView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addr_view);
            cityView=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_view);
            cardView = (CardView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.card_list);
        }

    }
}
```

I have two buttons Save and show_details,The app crashes when i click show_details if there are no values saved initially and raises an exception in getitemcount() method.

Comment: Before trying to see if it's empty or getDataStore, you should see if userDataStore in not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix getItemCount method like this

```
@Override 
public int getItemCount() { 
    if(userDataStore == null){return 0;}

     if(!userDataStore.getDataStore().isEmpty()&&userDataStore.getDataStore()!=null) {
            return userDataStore.getDataStore().size();
    } else{

            return 0;  
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the `userDataStore` in your class, but you assign a new value in the constructor.
In this way this variable can be `null`.

```
DataStore userDataStore=new DataStore();

public MyRecyclerAdapter(DataStore userDataStore)
{
    this.userDataStore=userDataStore;
}
```

You should check in your code if it is not null before using it.

In your `getItemCount` you can have a NPE, due to this reason.

```
  @Override 
  public int getItemCount() { 

    if(userDataStore != null && !userDataStore.getDataStore().isEmpty() && userDataStore.getDataStore()!=null) {
                return userDataStore.getDataStore().size();
    } else{

            return 0;  
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the `Datastore` in the `Adapter` and then in the constructor the param is a `DataStore` which means that you are already passing a newly created `DataStore` in the `Activity` that you are calling your `Adapter`. So just simplify your code:

```
DataStore userDataStore;

public MyRecyclerAdapter(DataStore userDataStore){
   this.userDataStore=userDataStore;
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return userDataStore.getDataStore().size();     
}
```

Hope it helps!!!